# displaying person before greeting

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I need those two to show in the same line(Now they show one after another). I tried many things but nothing works.

```
document.write();
var day = new Date();
var hr = day.getHours();

if ((hr == 1) || (hr == 2) || (hr == 3) || (hr == 4) || (hr == 5) || (hr == 
6) || (hr == 7) || (hr == 8) || (hr == 9) || (hr == 10)  || (hr == 11) || 
(hr == 12)) {
document.write("Good Morning!");
} 
if ((hr == 13) || (hr == 14) || (hr == 15) || (hr == 16) || (hr == 17)) {
document.write("Good Afternoon!");
}
if ((hr == 18) || (hr == 19) || (hr == 20) || (hr == 21) || (hr == 22) || 
(hr == 23) || (hr == 24)) {
document.write("Good Evening!");
}

document.write();
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
---------------------------*/
function myFunction() {
var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
if (person != null) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    person;
}
}
```

Comment: Whow, what are you doing? Why `document.write()` at the beginning and at the end? Why all the if-statements, when `if (hr <=12 ) { ... } else if ( hr >= 18 ) { ... } else { ...}` would suffice? Where in your html is an element with `id="demo"`?

Comment: Can you share the HTML?  The HTML and CSS is where you will do the presentation.

Comment: And by the way, hours can be `0` but not `24` ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I hope this'll Help you. i also done code optimization for if
>   Conditions.
>   **You have to invoke myfunction method**

```
    <body>
        <span id="demo"></span>
        <script>
        (function () {
        var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
        if (person != null) {
        document.write();
        var day = new Date();
        var hr = day.getHours();

        if ((hr >= 1) && (hr <= 12)) {
        person = person + " Good Morning!";
        } 
        else if ((hr >= 13) && (hr <= 17)) {
        person = person + " Good Afternoon!";
        }
        else if ((hr >= 18) && (hr <= 24)) {
        person = person + "Good Evening!" ;
        }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person;
        }
        })()

        </script>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var day = new Date();
    var hr = day.getHours();
    var greeting;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
    if (person != null) {
        if ( hr <= 12 ) {
            greeting = "Good morning " + person;
        } else if ( hr <= 18 ) {
            greeting = "Good afternoon " + person;
        } else {
            greeting = "Good evening " + person;
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = greeting;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.write() does not add a new line to document but rather changes your document element to the content, where as document.getElementById() refers to specific element in the DOM. Anyway here is my 
**javascript:**

```
function greeting() {
  var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");

  if (person != null) {
    // Set hr to current hour
    var hr = new Date().getHours();

    // Tests current hour
    if (hr > 0 && hr < 13) {
        document.write("Good Morning! " + person);
    } else if (hr > 12 && hr < 18) {
        document.write("Good Afternoon! " + person);
    } else if (hr > 17 && hr < 25) {
        document.write("Good Evening! " + person);
    }
  }
}
```